# Type Casting Error while i try to do deserialization

Tags: java, typecasting-operator

Why is it giving me the error "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Customer" When i have the Customer class in the Same source package as the funcion that is calling it.

```
public void getEmployee() {
Customer cu =null;
  try {
     Customer e = new Customer();
     FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("Customers.ser");
     ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
     cu =(Customer) in.readObject();
     in.close();
     fileIn.close();
  } catch (IOException i) {
     i.printStackTrace();
     return;
  } catch (ClassNotFoundException c) {
     System.out.println("Employee class not found");
     c.printStackTrace();
     return;
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think we can know what your problem is from what you show here.  Ideally, you should show the whole file that this method comes from, along with the filename.  Also provide the whole file for the Customer class.  If these files are too big to do that, then cut out unimportant information but keep all of the structure, as that's what's going to be important to this question.  Then, explain to us how these two files are located on your disk, relative to each other.  Does "same source package" mean the two files are in the same directory?

Comment: This is perplexing. Can you tell which code line is pointed out by the compiler?

Comment: Can you please add the sourcecode of `Customer` and also the snippet of code that you use to serialize to the file? Does serialization and deserialization happen in the same run of the code? Does `Customer` have a field `serialVersionUID` set?

Comment: And totally unrelated: why is your error message for the `ClassCastException` saying that the __Employee__ class is not found, while the classes name is `Customer` ?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you call the function a getter if it's not returning anything? Off hand though, I can point out few errors in the code. The `fileIn.close();` line is redundant. The stream is already closed by `in.close()`.  Most importantly, you don't need those `return;` statements. Essentially you can strip down the code to this:

```java
    public void getEmployee() {
        try {
            Customer e = new Customer();
            FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("Customers.ser");
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
            Customer cu = (Customer) in.readObject();
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**Edit**
Hang on a second. If it's a `"java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Customer"` you are getting, the problem is not here. It's most probably in the Serialization part. You're probably trying cast a blank file into Customer. Open the saved `Customers.ser` in a text editor. If you don't see a semblance of the data you stored, it's probably a problem with the serialization.

Answer (score -1):

Change from
Customer e = new Customer();
to
// Declare your object but don't instantiate("new") .
Customer e = null;

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).